# Transform apollo-datasource-rest response structure to adapt to the already defined remote schema

Tags: json, graphql, datasource, apollo-server, graphql-schema

We have remote schema already. We get Apollo datasource response by hitting the REST APIs using apollo-datasource-rest. The format of the json response does not match the schema. The task is to transform the json response to match the schema and return the result against the user query. How to achieve this?

E.g 
REST API response:

```
{
    "members": {
        "name": "john",
        "street_address": "10 Barley St."
    }
}
```

Our remote graphql schema:

```
type Users {
    username: String!
    street: String!
}
```

Any ideas or help or source code is highly appreciated.
Thanks again.

Comment: I am using node js, so should I use node-json-transform ? or is there any graphql tools available to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform the fields of REST API response to GraphQL Schema in GraphQL `resolver`. Or, delegate these transform operations to the model layer. This is a general approach.

If you think it's too verbose to transform the fields in resolvers or model layer manually.

You can use some library like [type-graphql](https://typegraphql.ml/) to do this. It combines your model layer and the GraphQL schema layer. It maps the fields of model to GraphQL schema fields.